# Find what proxy settings soapUI uses

Tags: proxy

I need the correct proxy settings to connect to a webservice. SoapUI is able to find those by setting proxy to 'automatic'. It then finds the right settings by looking at java, windows etc. 
But how can I then find what settings were actually used?

Comment: Did you mean to add more to your question? The last 3-words makes me wonder. "I know tho". Please edit your question.

Comment: @richMichaels tnx!